# What conditions can prevent layoutSubviews from being called after setNeedsLayout?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

### The problem

In a custom view of mine (a `UIScrollView` subclass) I am calling `setNeedsLayout` in response to a "reload data" event (triggered by an external source). Most of the time this works correctly and `layoutSubviews` is called when the next view layout cycle occurs. Sometimes, however, `layoutSubviews` is not called! Up until now I was living with the "certain knowledge" that `setNeedsLayout` *always* triggers `layoutSubviews`. Apparently I was wrong. I even tried calling `layoutIfNeeded` after `setNeedsLayout`, but still no success.

### The question

Obviously, I would like to solve my particular problem. On the other hand, I would like to improve my understanding of the view layout process on iOS, so I am formulating my question in a general way: Do you know of any conditions that can prevent `layoutSubviews` from being called after `setNeedsLayout` has been called? Answers that focus on `UIScrollView` are quite welcome, since that is where I am having trouble.

### Problem context

I am on iOS 7.1, using Xcode 5.1.1. Notes on the implementation of my custom scroll view:

- The scroll view has a single container view of type `UIView` that is always the same size as the scroll view content size
- The scroll view's `layoutSubviews` implementation places custom subviews into the container view by manually calculating the subviews' frames
- The custom subviews' implementation uses Auto Layout

Here is how the `reloadData` implementation looks like:

```
- (void) reloadData
{
  // Iterates through an internal array that holds the subviews,
  // then empties the array. Subviews are deallocated at this
  // point.
  [self removeAllSubviewsFromContainerview];
  self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
  // I verified that the content size is always greater than
  // CGSizeZero (both width and height)
  CGFloat contentWidth = [self calculateNewContentWidth];
  self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, self.frame.size.height);
  // Here is the problem: Sometimes this triggers layoutSubviews,
  // sometimes it does not.
  [self setNeedsLayout];
  // Adding the following line for debugging purposes does not
  // help, making it clear that setNeedsLayout has no effect.
  //   [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Last but not least, here are some observations I made:

- `layoutSubviews` is called as expected if the content offset or content size change. `layoutSubviews` is **not** called in my particular case if these two values don't change. I first assumed that this observation is a general working principle of `UIScrollView`, i.e. that `layoutSubviews` is generally not called for `UIScrollView` unless content offset or content size change. However, when I wrote a couple of minimal projects I failed to reproduce this assumed "general" behaviour - in those projects `layoutSubviews` was always called as expected, regardless of whether content offset or content size changed or not.
- `layoutSubviews` is always called as expected if the scroll view displays dummy `UILabel` instances instead of my own custom subviews
- `layoutSubviews` is always called as expected if I use my own custom subviews, but replace Auto Layout in the custom subviews' implementation by manual frame calculations

The last two observations have led me to believe that Auto Layout is somehow involved, but I really have no idea how this could affect how `setNeedsLayout` works.

Comment: are you calling -setNeedsLayout from within -layoutSubviews? I'm sure you're not doing it directly, because that would be rather stupid, but -layoutSubviews may call method -foo, -foo calls -bar and -bar calls -setNeedsLayout again. I think in that case, -layoutSubviews will not be called another time... maybe it helps...

Comment: @Michael Excellent idea! Unfortunately it's not the cause for my problem, but since I am also asking a general question here you might want to contribute this as an answer.

Comment: That sounds really frustrating, hopefully you figured it out.  I don't know if/where it is documented, but I just (re)learned the hard way that you can break the layout sequence by not calling the super implementation of a layout method.  Perhaps you had some logic screening a base method call.  In my case, layoutSubviews was not being called, and I traced that to my implementation of layoutSublayersOfLayer not calling super.layoutSublayersOfLayer.

Comment: Did you ever find out what's going on, @herzbube? I'm seeing similar behavior in the subview of a subview (and so on) of a UIScrollView as well. Setting setNeedsDisplay when the "data" property changes and later calling layoutIfNeeded, but layoutSubviews does not get called. It does get called however, if I call layoutIfNeeded right after setNeedsDisplay within the property's setter, so it seems something just resets the internal flag without ever calling layoutSubviews.

Comment: @fabianm No, I never found out, or I would have self-answered my question. To be honest, though, I didn't spend much time investigating the issue. I sidestepped the problem by changing my code to use `UICollectionView` instead of `UIScrollView`. An ugly temporary workaround I was using for some time was setting the `UIScrollView`'s scroll position (from within `reloadData`) to a **different** value, because that seemed to force `layoutSubviews` to be invoked: `self.contentOffset = /* something different */;` You'll have to find out yourself whether that is something that works for you™.

Comment: @herzbube Thank you for your suggestion. I also ended up with a workaround, without ever finding out what was going wrong in the first place.